# How to use customCell and Reorder in Kendo react Grid at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

So I am using Kendo React Grid and I am setting the reorder to true and also added a custom cell where I can show/hide columns.

when I don't reorder and try to show/hide everything works fine but when I reorder the columns and then try to hide then restore the column everything will get messy and I can't understand where I can control this.

[This is the grid at first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLvUF.png).

[This is where I reorder the columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKGOL.png)

[Now I opened the customCell and tried to hide the first column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ2TO.png)

[This is the result where I click on Save the order is changing and I don't know why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wewfb.png)

this is the Telerik documentation and in all examples there is no one where I can find reorder and customCell at the same time: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/

And this is the reorder section/ I couldn't find details about customizing the reorder: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/columns/reordering/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already got an answer on Github:
https://github.com/telerik/kendo-react/issues/400#issuecomment-559712491